# How can i store any variable in a file and load that in runtime specifically using a string in maui c#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I want to save variables in a file which will have specific keys and I want to load it using that keys.Suggest me two functions (that can take and use any variable and class as parameter) to that as cross platform approach in maui C#.I tried the code below and got the error.

tried this code:

```
public static void StoreData<T>(string key, T value)
{
    
    try
    {
        // Load existing data or create a new dictionary
        Dictionary<string, T> data;

        string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), AppInfo.Current.Name), "data.json");

        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                AppInfo.Current.Name)))

        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                AppInfo.Current.Name));
        }

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Create(filePath);
        }

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            data = new Dictionary<string, T>();
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, T>>(json);
        }

        data[key] = value;

        // Add or update the value associated with the key

        // Serialize and save the updated data to the file
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            writer.Write(json);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to save data: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

// Load data based on a key as an identifier
public static T LoadData<T>(string key, T defaultValue = default)
{
    try
    {
        // Load existing data or return the default value
        Dictionary<string, T> data;
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "data.json");

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, T>>(json);

                if (data != null)
                {
                    if (data.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        return data[key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to load data: {ex.Message}");
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Error is

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
  Source=System.Text.Json
  StackTrace:
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at book_companion_3.DataStorage.StoreData[T](String key, T value) in K:\Windows For Programming\Projects\Visual Studio\Apps\Maui\book companion 3\DataStorage.cs:line 78

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
JsonReaderException: The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
```

Comment: There is no reason for StoreData to read the file before writing it

Comment: When the file doesn't exist, you create one. Fine, but that's *empty*. Then you assume there is valid json there ...

Comment: i wanna save it and load it at runtime alike settings class of windows forms.But settings class does not support all data types

Comment: So, when the file doesn't exist, create it by writing *valid* data to it. Do note that when you write (for instance) DateTime data to it, you cannot add Guid data because the stored `Dictionary<String, DateTime>` will be treated as `Dictionary<string, Guid>`, which of course fails

Comment: MAUI has a built in key value store - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android

Comment: preference does not support all data types

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and met some problems:

**1. About the following part code:**

```
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            data = new Dictionary<string, T>();
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, T>>(json);
        }
```

This will throw an data cast exception when your data types are different between this time and the last time.

**2. The file path of the storing and loading are different.**

In the storing, it is:

`Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), AppInfo.Current.Name), "data.json");`

But in the loading it is:

`Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "data.json");`

It missed the `AppInfo.Current.Name`. So I deleted the code in the first problem and changed the path in the loading method.

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static void StoreData<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            try
            {
                // Load existing data or create a new dictionary
                Dictionary<string, T> data;

                string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), AppInfo.Current.Name), "data.json");

                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(
                        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                        AppInfo.Current.Name)))

                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(
                        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                        AppInfo.Current.Name));
                }

                if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    File.Create(filePath);
                }
                data = new Dictionary<string, T>();
                data[key] = value;

                // Add or update the value associated with the key

                // Serialize and save the updated data to the file
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
                {
                    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
                    writer.Write(json);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to save data: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

// Load data based on a key as an identifier
        public static T LoadData<T>(string key, T defaultValue = default)
        {
            try
            {
                // Load existing data or return the default value
                Dictionary<string, T> data;
                string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), AppInfo.Current.Name), "data.json");
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
                    {
                        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, T>>(json);

                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            if (data.ContainsKey(key))
                            {
                                return data[key];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return defaultValue;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to load data: {ex.Message}");
            return defaultValue;
            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           StoreData<List<string>>("hello",new List<string>() { "ASD","AAA"});
        }

        private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           var value = LoadData<List<string>>("hello",new List<string>());
        }
    }
```

After this, I can store the data and load it.

**Update:**

Change `writer.Write` to `writer.WriteAsync` will resolve the error op met.

Comment: but this does not solve my problem.That exception is thrown

'System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.books | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 10.'
InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.

+  ex {"The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.books | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 10."} System.Exception {System.Text.Json.JsonException}

Comment: the above code does not work for all classes and datatypes

Comment: 1. I didn't met the exception you got. 2. I tested above code with List, int and Model class, all the types of data and be stored and loaded. What type of data did you test? @incidiousworks

Comment: Did you tested it in maui???

Comment: Datatype was string and dictionary

Comment: Yes, I tested on maui windows and I tested the string and dictionary again. It worked. You can just copy my code and test. @incidiousworks

Comment: I wanna give you my source code.Will you please help me find the problem why my code for this serialization and deserialization is not working?How can i give you the solution?

Comment: You can post it on the github and give me the repo link. @incidiousworks

Comment: thanks but i solved it making write to writeasync

Comment: Glad to know you have solved it. I have updated the answer. Happy coding! @incidiousworks